# Confused Why I am getting C1010 error?

Tags: c++

I have three files:
Main, slist.h and slist.cpp can be seen at http://forums.devarticles.com/c-c-help-52/confused-why-i-am-getting-c2143-and-c1010-error-259574.html

I'm trying to make a program where main reads the list of student names from a file (roster.txt) and inserts all the names in a list in ascending order. This is the full class roster list (notCheckedIN). From here I will read all students who have come to write the exams, each checkin will transfer their name to another list (in ascending order) called present.

The final product is 
notCheckedIN will contain a list of all those students that did not write the exam and
present will contain the list of all students who wrote the exam

Main File:

```
// Exam.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "iomanip"
#include "fstream"
#include "string"
#include "slist.h"

using namespace std;

void OpenFile(ifstream&);
void GetClassRoster(SortList&, ifstream&);
void InputStuName(SortList&, SortList&);
void UpdateList(SortList&, SortList&, string);
void Print(SortList&, SortList&);
const string END_DATA = "EndData";

int main()
{

ifstream roster;
SortList notCheckedIn; //students present
SortList present; //student absent

OpenFile(roster);
if(!roster) //Make sure file is opened
return 1;
GetClassRoster(notCheckedIn, roster); //insert the roster list into the notCheckedIn list
InputStuName(present, notCheckedIn);
Print(present, notCheckedIn);
return 0;
}

void OpenFile(ifstream& roster)
//Precondition: roster is pointing to file containing student anmes
//Postcondition:IF file does not exist -> exit
{
string fileName = "roster.txt";
roster.open(fileName.c_str());

if(!roster)
cout << "***ERROR CANNOT OPEN FILE :"<< fileName << "***" << endl;
}
void GetClassRoster(SortList& notCheckedIN, ifstream& roster)
//Precondition:roster points to file containing list of student last name
// && notCheckedIN is empty
//Postcondition:notCheckedIN is filled with the names taken from roster.txt in ascending order
{
string name;
roster >> name;
while(roster)
{
notCheckedIN.Insert(name);
roster >> name;
}
}
void InputStuName(SortList& present, SortList& notCheckedIN)
//Precondition: present list is empty initially and notCheckedIN list is full
//Postcondition: repeated prompting to enter stuName
// && notCheckedIN will delete all names found in present
// && present will contain names present
// && names not found in notCheckedIN will report Error
{
string stuName;

cout << "Enter last name (Enter EndData if none to Enter): ";
cin >> stuName;
while(stuName!=END_DATA)
{
UpdateList(present, notCheckedIN, stuName);
}
}
void UpdateList(SortList& present, SortList& notCheckedIN, string stuName)
//Precondition:stuName is assigned
//Postcondition:IF stuName is present, stuName is inserted in present list
// && stuName is removed from the notCheckedIN list
// ELSE stuName does not exist
{
if(notCheckedIN.isPresent(stuName))
{
present.Insert(stuName);
notCheckedIN.Delete(stuName);
}
else
cout << "NAME IS NOT PRESENT" << endl;
}
void Print(SortList& present, SortList& notCheckedIN)
//Precondition: present and notCheckedIN contains a list of student Names present/not present
//Postcondition: content of present and notCheckedIN is printed
{
cout << "Candidates Present" << endl;
present.Print();

cout << "Candidates Absent" << endl;
notCheckedIN.Print();
}
```

Header File:

```
//Specification File: slist.h
//This file gives the specifications of a list abstract data type
//List items inserted will be in order
//Class SortList, structured type used to represent an ADT
using namespace std;
const int MAX_LENGTH = 200;
typedef string ItemType;
//Class Object (class instance) SortList. Variable of class type.
class SortList
{
//Class Member - components of a class, can be either data or functions
public:
//Constructor
//Post-condition: Empty list is created
SortList();

//Const member function. Compiler error occurs if any statement within tries to modify a private data
bool isEmpty() const;
//Post-condition: == true if list is empty
// == false if list is not empty

bool isFull() const;
//Post-condition: == true if list is full
// == false if list is full

int Length() const;
//Post-condition: size of list

void Insert(ItemType item);
//Precondition: NOT isFull() && item is assigned
//Postcondition: item is in list && Length() = Length()@entry + 1

void Delete(ItemType item);
//Precondition: NOT isEmpty() && item is assigned
//Postcondition:
// IF items is in list at entry
// first occurance of item in list is removed
// && Length() = Length()@entry -1;
// ELSE
// list is not changed

bool isPresent(ItemType item) const;
//Precondition: item is assigned
//Postcondition: == true if item is present in list
// == false if item is not present in list

void Print() const;
//Postcondition: All component of list have been output
private:
int length;
ItemType data[MAX_LENGTH];
void BinSearch(ItemType, bool&, int&) const;

};
```

Source File:

```
//Implementation File: slist.cpp
//This file gives the specifications of a list abstract data type
//List items inserted will be in order
//Class SortList, structured type used to represent an ADT
#include "iostream"
#include "slist.h"

using namespace std;
// int length;
// ItemType data[MAX_SIZE];
//Class Object (class instance) SortList. Variable of class type.
SortList::SortList()
//Constructor
//Post-condition: Empty list is created
{
length=0;
}

//Const member function. Compiler error occurs if any statement within tries to modify a private data
bool SortList::isEmpty() const
//Post-condition: == true if list is empty
// == false if list is not empty
{
return(length==0);
}

bool SortList::isFull() const
//Post-condition: == true if list is full
// == false if list is full
{
return (length==(MAX_LENGTH-1));
}

int SortList::Length() const
//Post-condition: size of list
{
return length;
}

void SortList::Insert(ItemType item)
//Precondition: NOT isFull() && item is assigned
//Postcondition: item is in list && Length() = Length()@entry + 1
// && list componenet are in ascending order of value
{
int index;
index = length -1;
while(index >=0 && item<data[index])
{
data[index+1]=data[index];
index--;
}
data[index+1]=item;
length++;
}

void SortList:elete(ItemType item)
//Precondition: NOT isEmpty() && item is assigned
//Postcondition:
// IF items is in list at entry
// first occurance of item in list is removed
// && Length() = Length()@entry -1;
// && list components are in ascending order
// ELSE data array is unchanged
{
bool found;
int position;

BinSearch(item,found,position);

if (found)
{
for(int index = position; index < length; index++)
data[index]=data[index+1];
length--;
}
}

bool SortList::isPresent(ItemType item) const
//Precondition: item is assigned && length <= MAX_LENGTH && items are in ascending order
//Postcondition: true if item is found in the list
// false if item is not found in the list
{
bool found;
int position;

BinSearch(item,found,position);
return (found);
}

void SortList::Print() const
//Postcondition: All component of list have been output
{
for(int x= 0; x<length; x++)
cout << data[x] << endl;
}

void SortList::BinSearch(ItemType item, bool found, int position) const
//Precondition: item contains item to be found
// && item in the list is an ascending order
//Postcondition: IF item is in list, position is returned
// ELSE item does not exist in the list
{
int first = 0;
int last = length -1;
int middle;

found = false;
while(!found)
{
middle = (first+last)/2;
if(data[middle]<item)
first = middle+1;
else if (data[middle] > item)
last = middle -1;
else
found = true;
}
if(found)
position = middle;
}
```

I cannot get rid of the C1010 error:
fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?

Is there a way to get rid of this error?
When I included "stdafx.h" I received the following 32 errors (which does not make sense to me why because I referred back to my manual on how to use Class method - everything looks a.ok.)

```
Error 1 error C2871: 'std' : a namespace with this name does not exist c:\..\slist.h 6
Error 2 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ItemType' c:\..\slist.h 8
Error 3 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int c:\..\slist.h 8
Error 4 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int c:\..\slist.h 8
Error 5 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ItemType' c:\..\slist.h 30
Error 6 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ItemType' c:\..\slist.h 34
Error 7 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ItemType' c:\..\slist.h 43
Error 8 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'data' c:\..\slist.h 52
Error 9 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int c:\..\slist.h 52
Error 10 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int c:\..\slist.h 52
Error 11 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ItemType' c:\..\slist.h 53
Error 12 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'item' c:\..\slist.cpp 41
Error 13 error C2761: 'void SortList::Insert(void)' : member function redeclaration not allowed c:\..\slist.cpp 41
Error 14 error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\..\slist.cpp 41
Error 15 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' c:\..\slist.cpp 45
Error 16 error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) c:\..\slist.cpp 45
Error 17 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'item' c:\..\slist.cpp 57
Error 18 error C2761: 'void SortList:elete(void)' : member function redeclaration not allowed c:\..\slist.cpp 57
Error 19 error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\..\slist.cpp 57
Error 20 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' c:\..\slist.cpp 65
Error 21 error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) c:\..\slist.cpp 65
Error 22 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'item' c:\..\slist.cpp 79
Error 23 error C2761: 'bool SortList::isPresent(void) const' : member function redeclaration not allowed c:\..\slist.cpp 79
Error 24 error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\..\slist.cpp 79
Error 25 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' c:\..\slist.cpp 83
Error 26 error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) c:\..\slist.cpp 83
Error 27 error C2065: 'data' : undeclared identifier c:\..\slist.cpp 95
Error 28 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'item' c:\..\slist.cpp 98
Error 29 error C2761: 'void SortList::BinSearch(void) const' : member function redeclaration not allowed c:\..\slist.cpp 98
Error 30 error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\..\slist.cpp 98
Error 31 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' c:\..\slist.cpp 103
Error 32 error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) c:\..\slist.cpp 103
```

Comment: I should probably wait more than 46 seconds before commenting, but hasty as I am can you please format the code properly? Select it and press Ctrl-k.

Comment: This is a homework question, isn't it?

Comment: You should write your assertions (pre,postconditions) in code, not in comments. Get your compiler's help whenever you can.

Comment: So, correct me if I misunderstood what you're trying to achieve: you want to read a file that has a bunch strings representing last-names. You want to insert these strings into a list that represents students checked-in. Then you want to read from stdin a list of names of students that are present, remove these students from the list of students checked-in and add them to a list that represents students present. Finally, you want both lists to be sorted in ascending order. Is that correct?

Comment: correct on your understanding on what my objective.
not a homework question (done school)
I tried formatting the code but thank you for doing it for me. I am going try your tip and see if it will work the next time I post my code up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because your project is configured to use precompiled header with the name of `stdafx.h` (which is the default setting for a new non-empty VC++ project). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zc28563(VS.80).aspx) for an instruction on how to turn that on or off (under "To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment").

As for errors you get with it - well, for one, you're `using namespace std` in your header file, but it does not include any headers that define anything from that namespace. You should `#include` standard headers for all types that you use in your header - `<string>`, for example.

Oh, and it should really be `#include <iostream>` (and same for all other standard headers), rather than `"iostream"`. The latter will normally work, but it is implementation-defined, and most implementations take it to mean "look in current directory first".

Comment: Thanks for helping me Pavel. 
Including the string library solved my problem.
Thanks for pointing out how I should include libraries that are in not in current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trashing your code and starting over.

Here are suggestions:
**1.  Use standard library functions and structures.**
Don't write wrappers around them.
For example, there is no need for an `OpenFile` method.  It just makes the program harder to read, wastes your time and *annoys the pig*.

**2.  Use angle brackets, < >, around standard headers.**
The angle brackets tell the compiler to search first in "system" or compiler directories first.

**3.  Read data then sort.**
Read all of your data into a {*standard*} container, then sort the container.  Sorting after every line wastes computer time and *annoys the pig*.

**4. Prefer to prefix `std` functions with `std`.**
For example, `std::cout` instead of `cout`.  Ah but you say "I can just include `using namespace std;`".  Yes, but this opens the doors wide open to everything in the `std` namespace.  Another mitigated solution is to identify each std function with namespace:  `using std::cout`.  Keep the namespace identities small.

**5.  Prefer EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE.**
Standard values to return from `main` are `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`.  These are defined in `<cstdlib>`.

**6.  Pass streams to your object's Print methods**
This will allow you to send the output to a file or the console without changing the object's code.  A good example is tracing the output.  Direct the output to a file so it doesn't disappear (like writing to a console).

**7.  Learn to use iterators and algorithms**
Standard containers support iterators.  You can easily print the contents of a `std::list` or `std::vector` by using `std::copy` and iterators.  The `std::sort` algorithm can be applied to containers by using iterators (except those containers that already have sort methods).

**8.  Keep it simple**
Keep your program as simple as possible, but no simpler.  Simple programs have fewer errors and run faster than large and complex programs (and they have less chance of annoying the pig).

---

*"Never teach a pig to sing, it wastes your time and annoys the pig."* -- Old joke
*"Everything should be as simple as possible, but no simpler."* -- paraphrasing Albert Einstein.

Comment: `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are C macros. In C++ you should return 0. Similarly, `NULL` is a C macro and in C++ we use 0 -- although that's for a different reason.

Answer (score 0):

### First Things First

As a general advice, always try to reuse [what you already have](http://cplusplus.com/reference/) and **know** works. The STL is **rich** with [tools](http://cplusplus.com/reference/) to solve exactly this sort of problems. Reuse mercilessly, steal code like there's no tomorrow. You'll get faster, better, stronger, sexier results this way.

### The Fast Solution

If you and only you write the roster file then maybe you can guarantee yourself that that file has a list of names that is always sorted. If you can rely on this guarantee then you can make your code faster and lighter. You won't need to load this file in memory first, and you won't need to sort the list you have in memory:

```
#include <iostream> // fstream,iterator,algorithm,string,vector

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    typedef std::vector<std::string> lastnames;
    lastnames present;
    std::copy(istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
              istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter(present));
    std::sort(present.begin(), present.end());
    lastnames absent;
    std::ifstream roster("roster.txt");
    std::set_difference(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(roster),
                        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                        present.begin(), present.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(absent));
    return 0;
}
```

### The Sure Solution

If you can't rely on the roster file being sorted then you'll have to sort it, and that implies you'll have to load it in memory.

```
    // ...
    std::ifstream roster("roster.txt");
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(roster),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter(absent));
    std::sort(absent.begin(), absent.end());
    lastnames::iterator e(std::set_difference(absent.begin(), absent.end(),
                                              present.begin(), present.end(),
                                              absent.begin()));
    absent.erase(e, absent.end());
    return 0;
}
```

### Taking a Peek at the Result

You can display the resultant list of checked-in-yet-not-present (or, absent) students like so:

```
cout << "Checked in, not present:\n";
copy(absent.begin(), absent.end(),
     ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```