# Error In VisualStudio2015 Program Will Not Run C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am in a class for C++ right now and took one of the examples from the book and am trying to run it through Visual Studio 2015, but despite there being no syntax errors (that I can see) it will not run the code. Here is the error message I get.[image: Error Message]

I am pretty positive it has nothing to do with the code, but I will post the code below just in case. Also, can you please explain to me step by step how to fix this for I am still not that familiar with the Visual Studio interface.

```
 //Ex7_02.cpp
//Creating and using boxes

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class CBox                      //Class definition at global scope
{
public:
    double m_Length;        //Lenght of box in inches
    double m_Width;         //Width of box in inches
    double m_Height;        //Height of box in inches
};

int main()
{
    CBox box1;                  //Declare box1 of type CBox
    CBox box2;                  //Declare box2 of type Cbox

    double boxVolume(0.0);      //Stores the volume of a box

    box1.m_Height = 18.0;           //Define the values of members of box1
    box1.m_Length = 78.0;
    box1.m_Width = 24.0;

    box2.m_Height = box1.m_Height - 10;     //Define box 2 members
    box2.m_Length = box1.m_Length / 2.0;
    box2.m_Width = 0.25*box1.m_Length;

    //Calculate volume of box1
    boxVolume = box1.m_Height*box1.m_Length*box1.m_Width;

    cout << endl << "Volume of box1 = " << boxVolume;

    cout << endl << "box2 has sides which total "
        << box2.m_Height + box2.m_Length + box2.m_Width
        << " inches.";

    cout << endl                        //Display the size of a box in memory
        << "A CBox object occupies "
        << sizeof box1 << " bytes.";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: Your message tells you exactly what the isssue is and how to fix it.

Comment: You have error messages at the bottom of the window. Google  the messages and see what comes up.

Comment: The project is set up to use a precompiled header, but the compiler cannot find one. So change the setting to NOT use precompiled headers.

Comment: The *text* of any compiler or run-time error messages should be included here, not pictures of tiny text.

Comment: Related & possible duplicates: [Unexpected end of file error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8862840/1441), [Confused Why I am getting C1010 error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823415/confused-why-i-am-getting-c1010-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
//Ex7_02.cpp
//Creating and using boxes
```

You preprocessor need it for project options.

Comment: thanks so much for the quick and simple reply. Worked like a charm.